# pm.Normal() in Python PyMC3

Tags: python-2.7, pymc3

I was working on a simple Bayesian linear regression using PyMC3 in python. In defining the likelihood function I came across this syntax.

```
likelihood = pm.Normal('Y', mu=intercept + x_coeff * df['x'],sd=sigma, observed=df['y'])
```

In the parameters for pm.Normal(), what does the "observed = " do?
Please explain with examples if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`observed` means that the value of the linear regression's response variable (typically named "y", but here confusingly named `likelihood`) is *known* (through observation) to be equal to `df[y]`.

When the inference algorithm is run, values `df['y']` will be used to determine the likely values of stochastic variables `intercept` and `x_coeff` that would have caused them. To do that, it uses the causal relationship between them, namely that the observed variable is Normally-distributed with mean equal to `intercept + x_coeff*df['x']` and standard deviation `sigma`.

Note that `df['y']` is typically an array with *multiple* observations. So the algorithm will try to infer the distributions of `intercept` and `x_coeff` likely to have induced these multiple observations `df['y']`.

Note that the algorithm will not infer the values for `df['x']` since that is also fixed, observed data.

I mentioned the variable was confusingly named `likelihood` instead of `y`. That is because `pm.Normal` does create a stochastic variable object, not a real-valued likelihood. I believe the reason this name was chosen was tradition, because the observed values define a likelihood that is internally used by the inference algorithm to infer the distributions for the other stochastic variables.

In fact, in the [PyMC introduction](https://www.pymc.io/projects/docs/en/stable/learn/core_notebooks/pymc_overview.html#model-specification) we see a similar definition using the name `Y_obs` instead:

```py
Y_obs = pm.Normal("Y_obs", mu=mu, sigma=sigma, observed=Y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you specify a probabilistic model, using a set of distributions and their relation to each other. In the below case we assume the random variable `y` follows a normal distribution with a mean we are unsure about, yet we have a belief its mean is positive and values close to 0 are more likely than greater values. We model this **prior** belief with a half normal distribution.

```
import numpy as np
import pymc3 as pm
import arviz as az

# specifying the model
# all random variables are unobserved

model = pm.Model()

with model:
    mean = pm.HalfNormal("mean", sigma=1)
    y = pm.Normal("y", mu=mean, sigma=1)
```

Let's now draw random samples from this model and visualise them:

```
with model:
    tr = pm.sample(1000, tune=5000, chains=2, cores=8, return_inferencedata=True)
```

```
with model:
    az.plot_trace(tr, var_names=["mean", "y"], divergences=None, legend=True, compact=False)
```

When you inspect the output of above cell you will see the samples for `mean` we drew follow the half normal distribution we specified, `y` accordingly shows a positive skew.

Now let's create some data:

```
y_obs = np.random.normal(loc=2, scale=1.0, size=1000)
```

As you can see the data we created follows a normal distribution with a mean of 2 (`loc=2`), quite different from our **prior** belief.

Now let's run our model again feeding it with our actual observations of random variable `y`.

```
model2 = pm.Model()

with model2:
    mean = pm.HalfNormal("mean", sigma=1)
    y = pm.Normal("y", mu=mean, sigma=1, observed=y_obs)
    
    tr = pm.sample(1000, tune=5000, chains=2, cores=8, return_inferencedata=True)
```

Visualise the samples:

```
with model:
    az.plot_trace(tr2, var_names=["mean"], divergences=None, legend=True, compact=False)
```

When you run this code you will see that the distribution we assume for mean has changed quite drastically. It is now tightly centered around 2, and seems to be rather normally distributed.

What happened is, that by providing data to the model `observed = y_obs` you specify a likelihood for all possible outcomes of `y`, by applying Bayes' theorem, the algorithm can infer the **posterior** distribution for the true value of `mean`.